Cross-Account S3 Access Denied Despite Correct Bucket Policy
I'm trying to set up cross-account access to an S3 bucket, allowing specific users from two different AWS accounts (Account A and Account B) to access the bucket. I’ve configured the bucket policy to allow actions such as s3:GetObject for specific IAM users in both accounts. While users from Account A can access the bucket successfully, users from Account B receive an "AccessDenied" error when trying to list or access objects in the bucket.
Here is the policy I've attached to the bucket:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny-all-unauthorized-access",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-Id:user/AccountA-user1", 
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-Id:user/AccountA-user2", 
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-Id:user/AccountA-user3", 
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-Id:user/AccountB-user1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::occ-infra-s3-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::occ-infra-s3-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow-actions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-Id:user/AccountA-user1", 
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-Id:user/AccountA-user2", 
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-Id:user/AccountA-user3", 
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-Id:user/AccountB-user1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket", 
                "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I expected the specified users from both accounts to be able to list and access the bucket contents based on the configured Allow statement, and the fact that they were excluded from the Deny. However, only the users from Account A are able to access the bucket. When Account B users attempt to access it, they encounter the following error:
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

In CloudTrail, I noticed that the userIdentity for Account A users correctly shows them as IAMUser, while for Account B users, the userIdentity appears as AWSAccount, which seems incorrect. Here is the relevant log entry for an Account A user:
"userIdentity": {
    "type": "IAMUser",
    "principalId": "AIDAQB7XESH6TMDGHIUEI",
    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-Id:user/AccountA-user1",
    "accountId": "AccountA-Id",
    "accessKeyId": "AKIAQB7JHUY87K7JHJ6X",
    "userName": "AccountA-user1"
}

And here is the log entry for the Account B user:
"userIdentity": {
    "type": "AWSAccount",
    "principalId": "AIDATACUJHYGDFERMLSJ7",
    "accountId": "AccountB-Id"
}

If I remove the deny statement from the bucket policy, the Account B user is able to access the bucket without issues. I believe this suggests that AWS is not recognizing the external IAM user correctly from Account B, and he is being denied access because of the NotPrincipal condition.
I also confirmed that the Account B user is correctly authenticated by running aws sts get-caller-identity, which returns the expected result:
{
    "UserId": "AIDATACUJHYGDFERMLSJ7",
    "Account": "AccountB-Id",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-Id:user/AccountB-user1"
}

AWS
S3
IAM
Cross-account-access
Bucket-policy

Presumably the S3 bucket is in account A. Does each IAM user in account B have its own IAM policy that explicitly allows S3 actions on account A's bucket/objects? See here.

When granting cross-account access, permissions must be configured in both accounts.
For example, let's say you have:

IAM User User-A in Account-A
S3 Bucket Bucket-B in Account-B

You would need to configure the following:

User-A would need an IAM Policy that grants permission to access Bucket-B (because IAM Users have no permissions by default, so they would not be allowed to use S3 unless a policy grants this access)
Bucket-B needs a Bucket Policy that grants User-A permission to access the bucket

Also, please note that Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. Therefore, you should not create a Deny policy unless you have a specific need to revoke permissions that were granted elsewhere. For example, if an Admin has permissions to access "all S3 buckets", but you then specifically want to revoke their access to a sensitive bucket, then you would use a Deny policy. Otherwise, they are best avoided since they can cause confusion in how policies are evaluated.
